# Python Regex - How to extract the third portion?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

My input is of this format: `(xxx)yyyy(zz)(eee)fff` where {x,y,z,e,f} are all numbers. But `fff` is optional though.

Input: `x = (123)4567(89)(660)`

Expected output: Only the `eee`part i.e. the number inside 3rd "()" i.e. 660 in my example.

I am able to achieve this so far:

```
re.search("\((\d*)\)", x).group()
```

Output: (123)

Expected: (660)

I am surely missing something fundamental. Please advise.

Edit 1: Just added `fff` to the input data format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find all those matches that have round braces `()`, and print the third match with `findall`

```
import re
n = "(123)4567(89)(660)999"
r = re.findall("\(\d*\)", n)
print(r[2])
```

Output:

```
(660)
```

Comment: It's not about 3 digits inside round braces, but finding the number inside the third set of round braces"()"

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I updated my answer, I made it print the third set using `findall` by printing the 3rd match.

Answer (score 1):

The `(eee)` part is identical to the `(xxx)` part in your regex. If you don't provide an anchor, or some sequencing requirement, then an unanchored search will match the first thing it finds, which is `(xxx)` in your case.

If you know the `(eee)` always appears at the end of the string, you could append an "at-end" anchor (`$`) to force the match at the end. Or perhaps you could append a following character, like a space or comma or something.

Otherwise, you might do well to match the other parts of the pattern and not capture them:

```
pattern = r'[0-9()]{13}\((\d{3})\)'
```

Comment: Thanks, i've just added `fff` to my input data format.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the third group of numbers in brackets, you need to skip the first two groups which you can do with a repeating non-capturing group which looks for a set of digits enclosed in `()` followed by some number of non `(` characters:

```
x = '(123)4567(89)(660)'
print(re.search("(?:\(\d+\)[^(]*){2}(\(\d+\))", x).group(1))
```

Output:

```
(660)
```

[Demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/BUN20689)